# Как сделать выборку из выборки?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Я делаю выборку из таблицы
data = self.cursor.execute("SELECT * FROM main")
Затем мне нужно сделать выборку из data
Мне это нужно для создания фильтрующих полей.
Например в базе такие данные:

1 | 21 | A
2 | 44 | B
3 | 42 | C

Сначала в data лежат все 3 строки, потом я делаю фильтр по 2 столбцу со значением 2(LIKE %2%)
Результат:

1 | 21 | A
3 | 42 | C

Затем я хочу отфильтровать эти 2 строки.
Я понимаю что можно при каждом фильтре проверять все поля и создавать комбинации типо: .... C3 LIKE %C% AND C2 LIKE %2%

Но есть ли возможность сделать так как я хочу?

Comment: А как вы применяете like, когда у вас данные уже находятся в data ? Вы это привели для понимания общего смысла и подразумеваете некую фильтрацию данных методами python. Или все таки вы передаете в самом запросе этот like

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Я отмечал ранее что вопрос не решен, т.к. в вопросе написано "Затем", то есть мне не нужно отфильтровать одним запросом по 2 параметрам, я повторюсь, я хочу сейчас сделать запрос "WHERE col3 LIKE '%2%'", а ПОТОМ, через минут 10 может быть, из того что у меня есть в cursor выбрать  WHERE col3 LIKE '%C%'. Я решил проблему, скорее всего не правильно, генерируя запрос типа "C3 LIKE %C% AND C2 LIKE %2%" проверяя все поля для фильтров.

Comment: Я добавил вариант с использованием `view`

Comment: @SergeyNudnov Это решение уже ближе, как я понял отфильтровать то, что лежит в курсоре(после запроса к бд) нельзя? Возможно это решение лучше используемого мною сейчас. Спасибо.

Comment: То, что лежит в курсоре, можно обрабатывать питоном, только зачем? Вы можете заменить VIEW на TABLE и генерировать временную таблицу. Но в этом случае данные в ней будут отвязаны от основной таблицы. То есть, при изменении основной таблицы - временная останется неизменной

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Самый простой вариант - запрос в запросе:

```
sql = """
    SELECT *
    FROM (
      SELECT *
      FROM test
      WHERE col2 LIKE '%2%'
    )
    WHERE col3 = 'A'
"""
data = self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

Смотрите пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/295a1/3)

Учтите, что внутренний запрос фактически генерирует временную таблицу, без индексов. Поэтому если он возвращает очень много строк, то внешний запрос будет работать с полным сканированием этих строк - медленно.

Гораздо лучше, если все необходимые условия скомбинированы в одинарном запросе, как для примера выше:

```
sql = """
    SELECT *
    FROM test
    WHERE col2 LIKE '%2%'
      AND col3 = 'A'
"""
data = self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

Также можно использовать JOIN операторы, соединяя таблицу с самой собой. Но это достаточно сложный подход.

### Views

Можно использовать Views:

```
sql = """
    CREATE VIEW test_filtered
    AS
       SELECT *
       FROM test
       WHERE col2 LIKE '%2%';
"""
self.cursor.execute(sql)
sql = """
    SELECT *
    FROM test_filtered
    WHERE col3 = 'A';
"""
self.cursor.execute(sql)
```

Смотрите пример на [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/ad4b0/2)

Не забывайте удалять View после использования:

```
DROP VIEW [IF EXISTS] view_name;
```

Comment: Я написал более простой вариант в вопросе
SELECT * FROM test WHERE col3 LIKE '%C%' AND col2 LIKE '%2%'
Но хотелось бы сделать запрос к результату запроса

Comment: @ИванКакуркин Запрос в запросе, как в первом примере, это именно оно.